# Replace filter instead of appending for same attribute in catalog layer navigation

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation, filter

I want to slightly modify the catalog layer navigation function. I have an attribute named "book_type" having four possible values. What I want to do is that; when user selects any value from the four then the filter is performed.

Now the user must again be able to select any value from the above four options but in a way that, the previous filter of the attribute book_type must be removed and replaced with the new filter.

Hence instead of appending , the filter should be replaced for the same attribute type.

What should I do to modify this?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party extension. Please contact the extension provider or don't use the extension if it doesn't fit your needs. The desired behavior is the standard behavior of Magento without the extension.

Comment: ok then what if I have to change the default behavior without using the extension? I modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad subject. The Layered Nav feature of magento is kind of big and not that easy to modify. I doubt that you will get a fully working solution in here.
You would have to rewrite a lot of classes in order to achieve this.
I would start by looking at the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_State` and `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State` classes. Those are the ones that hold the selected filters. You should find a way to integrate the functionality provided by these classes with the rest of the layered navigation.
By default, when you select a filter value, the filter is not present in the available filters anymore. It is moved to a separate section rendered by the block I mentioned above `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State`.  You should find a way to avoid this and still have the filters present in the filters list.
I honestly recommend using an extension. On long term is much cheaper than trying it yourself.
I can recommend 2 paid extensions that I've used in the past and they did the job:

- http://www.manadev.com/magento-extensions/seo-layered-navigation-plus
- https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

I'm in no way associated to the developers of these extension. I just used them and liked them.

Comment: Thanks Marius!! Alright.. Will any one of the above extensions do the exact thing I want?? If yes then which one and how??

Comment: @Helly Both of them do even more that you want. See the links I posted. both of them have demos. If you have less than about 10k products I recommend the first one. If you have more, I suggest using the second one.